# ElasticSearch 8.5 and trying to set up Java CRUDS for Client, getting weird error with Jackson

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jackson, client

I am trying to use ElasticSearchClient 8.5.1.I followed official pages on ElasticSearch website and tried a simple index and search operation.I am getting an error message that is not letting me move ahead..
Link I used:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Java Code:

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("somehost", 443)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

    RestClient restClient = builder.build();

    System.out.println(restClient.getNodes());
    System.out.println(restClient.isRunning());

    try{

    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient,
            new JacksonJsonpMapper()
    );

    ElasticsearchClient esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);



        TermQuery termQuery= QueryBuilders.term().field("title").value("Rocky Mountain").build();


    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder().index("search-profile").query(termQuery._toQuery())
            .build();
        SearchResponse<Places> response=null;

        try {
           response= esClient.search(searchRequest, Places.class);
            response.hits().hits().stream().forEach(modelHit -> System.out.println(modelHit.source().getVisitors()));

        }
        catch (IOException de){
            System.out.println("Exception handling"+de);
        }
```

Exception I get:

Exception in thread "main"

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Jackson exception: Unrecognized token 'Client': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.convertException(JacksonJsonpParser.java:84)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.fetchNextToken(JacksonJsonpParser.java:91)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.next(JacksonJsonpParser.java:118)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:70)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:79)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:280)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:148)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1518)
    at com.godaddy.ConnectWith.main(ConnectWith.java:74)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Client': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:745)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2734)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:902)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.fetchNextToken(JacksonJsonpParser.java:89)
    ... 8 more

... 8 more
```

More Info:

I guess this API is still in dev phase and not GA.When I debugged the code and went through library classes it showed and response of 400 that is Bad request.Now I don't know how and why it is showing me a bad request

```
private Response performRequest(final NodeTuple<Iterator> tuple, final InternalRequest request, Exception previousException)
Class RestClient
httpResponse = client.execute(context.requestProducer, context.asyncResponseConsumer, context.context, null).get();
```

Library builds following request and sends ignore without me setting this in...,making the whole debugging bit more difficult than it really is..

```
Request{method='POST', endpoint='/search-profile/_search', params={typed_keys=true, ignore=400,401,403,404,405}, entity=[Content-Type: application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8,Content-Length: 56,Chunked: false], options=RequestOptions{headers=X-Elastic-Client-Meta: es=8.5.1,jv=19,hl=2,t=8.5.1,hc=4.1.5,User-Agent: elastic-java/8.5.1 (Java/19.0.1),Accept: application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8}}
```

Response I get:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request  [Chunked: false]
```

Comment: Hey, do you really need "_toQuery" ??? I think passing  termQuery  should be enough...

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. The issue was that I am trying to connect to secured host that is not defined as such.
**HttpHost** class default schema is **HTTP**.
I solved the issue by providing https schema into HttpHost constructor.

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("somehost", 443, "https")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a more modern version of ElasticSearch and Spring Boot when connecting to my cloud managed instance.

I had to add `.usingSsl()` on my ClientConfiguration builder...

```
@Override
public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    return ClientConfiguration.builder()
         .connectedTo("url:port")
         .usingSsl()  // <--- This was missing before
         .build();
}
```